# Uniformly convergence of solution in Weak maximum principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

For $T<\infty$， if $\phi: [0,T] \rightarrow R$  solves
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\phi}{dt} =F(\phi(t),t)  
\\
&\phi(0) =\alpha 
\end{align}
where $F(x,t)$ is smooth. Then, how to show there is $\epsilon_0>0$ such that , for any $0<\epsilon\le \epsilon_0$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\phi_\epsilon}{dt} =F(\phi_\epsilon(t),t)  +\epsilon
\\
&\phi_\epsilon(0) =\alpha +\epsilon
\end{align}
has solution $\phi_\epsilon$ on $[0,T]$ ?   Besides, how to show $\phi_\epsilon \rightarrow \phi$ uniformly ?

PS: This problem is from the proof of Theorem 3.1.1 (Weak maximum principle for scalars) of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow.  I have a little knowledge of ODE, just know some first order equation and its local existence.

Comment: This can be found in ode text. Did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar  Could you recommend a book about ODE ( not too complex). I just have a very simple one.

Comment: I remembered finding this result [here](https://books.google.dk/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=LdTZJ4HwCv4C&redir_esc=y), in the first chapter. In general this is a good book.